# I need Microsoft.Practices.Unity and ObjectBuilder2 sources

Tags: .net, unity-container

Where can I get the sources for these 2 assemblies? I have some issues with them an would need to debug inside them.

Basically the problem i have is that i register a class with

```
container.RegisterType<Interface, Type>()
```

and in some cases i get a new instance, and in other cases i get an old instance of the class.

***Edit:*** 
I figured it out, i only had to change the references in the Prism projects to the new Unity (DOH!!!) Stupid me...

Well, you were all right, and thanks for opening my eyes and for the quick answers.

NOW IT'S DEBUGGING TIME!!!

Comment: It's not the source so you can't debug through it, but you could use Reflector to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the source here: http://www.codeplex.com/unity

Answer (score 1):

I got it as part of the Enterprise Library

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=1643758B-2986-47F7-B529-3E41584B6CE5&displaylang=en

Here's the source control checkin list.  You can download whichever version matches the one you have.

http://unity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/

looking....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried on this site?  http://unity.codeplex.com/

Comment: yes, but it's not the same. 
I have Microsoft.Practices.Unity  and ObjectBuilder2 that came with PRISM. I tried replacing the references to this project instead, but it doesn't work.